# Binary conversion returning decimal value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to display all the binary numbers which are divisible by 5 and I am able to successfully show them. But the output is in decimal format even though I have converted them to base 2 (binary).

My code -

```
user_input = raw_input("Enter three numbers separated by commas: ")
input_list = user_input.split(',')
decimal_list=[]
binary_list=[]
for i in input_list:
     decimal_list.append(int(i,2))
print decimal_list
for x in decimal_list:
    if x%5==0:
        binary_list.append(int(str(x),10))
print binary_list
```

My input

```
0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000
```

Output -

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 5]
```

Why do I get **[0,5]** instead of **[0000,0101]** ? I did convert them back to binary using **(int(str(x),10))**

Comment: because python representation of a list of integers is done in base 10.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar How do i convert it to binary then ? Or how do I represent the list in binary format ?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a list of integers and you use `print` on it, you're implicitly calling `list.__repr__()` method on it.

This method creates a string with integer numbers *in base 10* separated with commas and wrapped with brackets.

If you want to print in binary, you could create a special list object (inheriting from `list`) and change the way it's represented:

```
class BinaryList(list):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "[{}]".format(",".join("0b{:04b}".format(x) for x in self))

user_input = "0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000"
input_list = user_input.split(',')
decimal_list=[]
binary_list=BinaryList()   # here we're using our special class
for i in input_list:
     decimal_list.append(int(i,2))
print(decimal_list)
for x in decimal_list:
    if x%5==0:
        binary_list.append(int(str(x),10))
print(binary_list)
```

that prints:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0b0000,0b0101]
```

This list is specialized: if you enter strings in it, the `__repr__` method will fail because of incompatible format. Also note that I have added the `0b` prefix in the representation to be able to copy/paste the result & keep the proper values, and avoid mixing it up with decimals.